# How do you access an object's attribute declared as a list within another object?

Tags: c#, iteration

These are my object types:

```
public class Room
{


    public Giver Giver
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    [XmlElement("Receiver")] 
    public List<Receiver> Receiver
    {
        get;
        set;
    }



}

 public class Receiver
{
    [XmlAttribute("type")]
    public string Type
    {
        get; set;
    }

    [XmlAttribute("Id")]
    public String Id
    {
        get; set;
    }


}

     class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {

 List<Room> list = new List<Room>
        {
            new Room
            {

                Giver = new Giver{ Type="Generous",  PID="something"},
                Receiver = new List<Receiver>{new Receiver{Type="test1", Id="test2"},
                                              new Receiver{Type="test3", Id="test4"},
                                              new Receiver{Type="test5", Id="test6"}},




            }


        };

    }


}
```

If I declare  **List eroom**, How can I iterate through the eroom list, in which a Receiver list is declared and access the attributes of Receiver?

For example, I have:

```
List<Room> eroom;



 for (int i = 0; i < eroom.Count; i++)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Giver Type: " + eroom[i].Giver.Type);
            Console.WriteLine("Giver PID: " + eroom[i].Giver.PID);

           //code below returns error
           Console.WriteLine("Receiver Id: " + eroom[i].Receiver.Id);

        }
```

How can I access Receiver's Id inside the for loop?

Comment: Please ask wat you exactly want to do?. Already you have posted code to access receiver id? Wat error it returns

Answer (score 0):

```
List<Room> eroom;
eroom.ForEach((room) =>{


            Console.WriteLine("Giver Type: " + room.Giver.Type);
            Console.WriteLine("Giver FNm: " + room.Giver.PID);
           room.Receiver.ForEach((receiver) =>{

            Console.WriteLine(receiver.Id);

             });

});
```

Answer (score 0):

You need a second loop inside the `eroom` one. Since `Receiver` (the variable, not the class) is a list, there are multiple Ids in each one.
You would need something like this:

```
foreach (Receiver r in eroom[i].Receiver)
    Console.WriteLine("Receiver Id: " + r.Id;
```

You could also use a normal for loop, using 0 and eroom[i].Reciever.Count as bounds.